# How do I hide using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Good evening everyone,

I'm new to jQuery and I'm having trouble with the hide() function. I did the code as instructed but I seem to still be having an issue.

Thank you,
Ed

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $("p.class-text").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(5000);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <a href="http://www.castro4designs.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/home.png" height="240" width="356" alt="4Design Home Page"></a>
    <p class="card-text">Castro4design.com was my first official website which was done for my 'Intro to New Media Tech' class. The site consist of basic HTML and CSS. The site was to keep track of all our work throughout our college career.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't reference jquery file properly. Pls check.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do.

Comment: There is no `p.class-text`....

Comment: can't see `hide()` being called anywhere -.-

Answer (score 3):

you already don't have `p` with class `class-text` your `p` class is `card-text`

use `$("p.card-text")` instead of `$("p.class-text")`

Answer (score 0):

You should use same class names: "card-text" for example. Also added jQuery tag to your snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $("p.card-text").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
    <a href="http://www.castro4designs.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/home.png" height="240" width="356" alt="4Design Home Page"></a>
    <p class="card-text">Castro4design.com was my first official website which was done for my 'Intro to New Media Tech' class. The site consist of basic HTML and CSS. The site was to keep track of all our work throughout our college career.</p>
</div>
```